# jquery: оптимальный способ получения атрибутов нескольких элементов

Tags: jquery, поиск

Есть такая структура элементов:

```
<div class = 'objects'>
    <div class = 'object'><div class = 'time' time-data = '123'></div></div>
    <div class = 'object'><div class = 'time' time-data = '123'></div></div>
    <div class = 'object'><div class = 'time' time-data = '123'></div></div>
    <div class = 'object'><div class = 'time' time-data = '123'></div></div>
</div>
```

Я хочу обработать каждый элемент `.time` в `.objects`.

На ночь голова не варит, поэтому сделал так:

```
var objects = $('.objects').children();
var object = $(objects[0]).children('.time');

var data = parseInt(object.attr('time-data')));
```

Совсем не оптимально. В общем забил микроскопом гвоздь.

Вроде можно как-то "в одну строчку" сделать типа:

```
$(.objects .object .time).every(function(){
    var data = this.attr('time-data');
});
```

Comment: `every` -> `each`. что значит обработать?

Comment: `$(".objects .object .time").each( function() { var data = $(this).attr('time-data'); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".objects .object .time").each(function() {
  var data = $(this).attr('time-data');
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='objects'>
  <div class='object'>
    <div class='time' time-data='1231'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='object'>
    <div class='time' time-data='1232'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='object'>
    <div class='time' time-data='1233'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='object'>
    <div class='time' time-data='1234'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```